# Postgresql Encoded and decoded

Tags: postgresql

I have a table abc, in which one column name where some data is encoded and some are not encoded. When I run the decode query the exception is found. How to handle it. There is a large number of rows in this table.

```
create table abc
(
id serial primary key,
name varchar(500)
)

select decode(name,'base64') from abc;
```

> exception occurs: SQL state: 22023

Now how can I convert all non-encoded data to encoded? Or how can I handle this exception.

Comment: Give some example data.The encoded data needs to be in the correct format

Comment: some data like this YWJj - encoded data and some are like this test - non encoded data in same columns name. How can i handles it.

Comment: Why did you change the chosen answer? Did my method not work for you? It should be a lot faster.

Comment: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
SQL state: 22021 @EvanCarroll

Comment: @SaddamKhan that has nothing to do with any answer, it's impossible to store NUL in a varlena (varchar/text) field in PostgreSQL because they're NUL terminated. Can you create a test case... How are you inserting that 0x00? Try this with the `abc` table in your question `INSERT INTO abc (name) VALUES (chr(0)::varchar(500));` You will get `ERROR:  null character not permitted`

Comment: @EvanCarroll data inserted from application. I don't know how it inserted.

Comment: It could not have inserted. Something isn't right. A text field can not have a 0x00. I'm confused at what you're doing, but what you're saying is impossible. C-Strings, as used in PostgreSQL, are nul terminated. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses [POSIX regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html). If we had a regular expression, we could see if the input matched. If so feed it to decode, otherwise return it as-is. This [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/475217/124486) provides us one such regex,

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$
```

Keep in mind, decode returns `bytea`. We explicitly cast `name` to bytea here because if it isn't Base64, we need to be sure we return the same type. This would look like this,

```
SELECT name, CASE
  WHEN name ~ '^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$'
  THEN decode(name,'base64')
  ELSE name::bytea
END AS name_maybe_decoded
FROM abc;
```

This will return

1. `name` decoded as Base64, if the input looks to be Base64.
2. `name` as-is.

Try it..

```
SELECT name, CASE
  WHEN name ~ '^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$'
  THEN decode(name,'base64')
  ELSE name::bytea
END AS name_maybe_decoded
FROM ( VALUES
  ('VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0IGRhdGE='),
  ('foobar'),
  ('SEFMTE8='),
  ('NOTBase64=')
) AS t(name);
```

Now remember, that's still the binary representation of the text, and the base64 decoded. You can output that as text using [`convert_from`](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201101281445.p0SEjjdN078867@wwwmaster.postgresql.org)

```
WITH t2 AS (
  SELECT name, CASE
    WHEN name ~ '^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$'
    THEN decode(name,'base64')
    ELSE name::bytea
  END AS name_maybe_decoded
  FROM ( VALUES
    ('VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0IGRhdGE='),
    ('foobar'),
    ('SEFMTE8='),
    ('NOTBase64=')
  ) AS t(name)
)
SELECT convert_from(name_maybe_decoded, 'UTF8')
FROM t2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be way off because the question is extremely vague, but you could try something like this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
x character varying[] := SELECT name FROM abc;
z record;
BEGIN
FOR z IN x
LOOP
    SELECT decode(z, 'base64');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN SQLSTATE '22023' THEN encode(z, 'base64');
END LOOP;
END; $$
```

Comment: Slower than my method below. I can't see any advantage to this.